# Main website and Subdomain Mobile Website (facing user directories issue)

Tags: php, html, mysql, directory, web

I have main website on one domain and now I am working for m.domain.com (mobile sub-domain).

On my main website users register themselves and a directory is automatically created in website.

Now as I am working on different directory for m.domain, users register themselves and directory is created in m.domain, but it is not created in main website. So i am stuck.

I want to have common user's directories even when they login from main domain or m.domain.com

Here's image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not use different directories for your domains.

You have (at least) two options:

- configure your web server so that both domains (`domain.com` and `m.domain.com`) point to the same directory (e.g. virtual hosts - refer to your web server documentation)
- configure URL redirects, so that any `m.domain.com/page.php` actually opens `domain.com/page.php?mobile=1`, where `mobile=1` is a GET parameters.

In both cases, you have one set of PHP scripts, and the script can deliver the main/mobile content dependent on how it was called (either `m.domain.com` or due to a `mobile` GET parameter).